# Feminine Definite Article

Tags: pronoun, standard-german, definite-article

> Die Lampe ist klasse, sie ist nicht langweilig.

Why is there *sie* after the comma, is that *sie* for lampe (die Lampe).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *»sie«* is not an article! It is a personal pronoun. It refers to a noun or a nominal group that has feminine gender. A personal pronoun always can be replaced by the noun or a nominal group to which it refers (you just need to correct the grammatical case if it is different).

Here *»sie«* refers to a nominal group, and this group consists of two words:

- nominal group: **die Lampe**

  - **die**
    definite feminine article in nominative case singular
  - **Lampe**
    a feminine noun in nominative case singular

Since **sie** also is in nominative case, you don't need to change case when you replace the personal pronoun by the nominal group:

> Die Lampe ist klasse, **die Lampe** ist nicht langweilig.

We have two full sentences here, which are joined together by a coma. You could separate them with a full stop too:

> Die Lampe ist klasse. **Sie** ist nicht langweilig.
>   Die Lampe ist klasse. **Die Lampe** ist nicht langweilig.

---

An example where you need to change the case when you replace:

> Der Berg ist hoch. Ich werde **ihn** morgen besteigen.

*»Berg«* is a masculine noun. Here *der Berg* is in nominative case, but the personal pronoun *»ihn«* which refers to the nominal group *»der Berg«* is in accusative case. So, the replacement must be in accusative case too:

> Der Berg ist hoch. Ich werde **den Berg** morgen besteigen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. Deutsch is a beautiful language but some concepts are quite hard to grasp.

Comment: The *sie* corresponds to *it* in *The lamp is great, it is not boring.* The difficulty is that *it* translates to *er*, *sie*, or *es* depending on the gender of the noun it refers to.